# Unix Java Issue

Tags: java, unix, ubuntu, websphere

Ok, I'm trying to install Websphere (from IBM) on my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Server.

But when it cames to install the *.bin*, it says no Java VM can be found on the server, but when I get the Java version it's fine.

Here's the response I get when I run this commands:

```
$ sudo path/*.bin

Preparing to install ...
Extracting the installation resources from the installer archive..
Configuring the installer for this system's environment...
no Java virtual machine could be found from your PATH environment variable. You must install a VM prior to running this program.


$ java -version

java version "1.6.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build pxi3260sr12-20121025_01(SR12))
IBM J9 VM (build 2.4, JRE 1.6.0 IBM J9 2.4 Linux x86-32 jvmxi3260sr12-20121024_126067 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
J9VM - 20121024_126067
JIT - r9 20120914_26057
GC - 20120925_AA)
JCL - 20121014_01

$ cat /etc/environment

JAVA_HOME="/opt/ibm/java-i386-60"
JRE="$JAVA_HOME/jre"
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/opt/imb/java-i386-60/bin:/opt/ibm/java-i386-60/jre/bin"
```

Comment: Try `sudo java -version` and see what you get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `sudo`, the command is run as `root` and not as the current user. You need to configure `root`'s `$PATH` to include Java.

Try `sudo java -version` to see if Java is property configured for `root` (it sounds like it isn't).